# Self-Hosted build agent - CS2012: Cannot open .dll for writing, access denied

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild

My self-hosted build agent started reporting an error during dotnet build yesterday.  Full command:

`C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src>"C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" build C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.csproj "-dl:CentralLogger,\"C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.168.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"*ForwardingLogger,\"C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\_tasks\DotNetCoreCLI_5541a522-603c-47ad-91fc-a4b1d163081b\2.168.0\dotnet-build-helpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll\"" --configuration release`

Expected build to work fine.  Actual output:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.6.0-preview-20126-02+13cfe7fc5 for .NET Core
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
  You are using a preview version of .NET Core. See: https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-preview
##vso[task.logdetail id=8d38fe20-6aaa-4bc0-a56a-6659df9b8b93;parentid=;name=CSC;type=Build;starttime=2020-05-08T16:07:55.6837318Z;state=InProgress;]
##vso[task.logissue type=Error;sourcepath=CSC;linenumber=0;columnnumber=0;code=CS2012;]Cannot open 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' is denied.'
##vso[task.logdetail id=8d38fe20-6aaa-4bc0-a56a-6659df9b8b93;parentid=;type=Build;result=Failed;finishtime=2020-05-08T16:07:55.6892238Z;progress=100;state=Completed;parentid=;name=;]
CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' is denied.' [C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.csproj]

Build FAILED.

CSC : error CS2012: Cannot open 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' for writing -- 'Access to the path 'C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\obj\release\netstandard2.1\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.dll' is denied.' [C:\agent\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.166.4\_work\19\s\src\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest\Cloud.Core.Extensions.Nest.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:00.83
```

Project file for csproj is defined as:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Company></Company>
    <Version>3.1</Version>
    <PackageIconUrl></PackageIconUrl>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <Description>A set of extension methods for the Elasticsearch Nest client</Description>
    <PackageTags>Nest Elasticsearch Extension Cloud.Core .net-Core Core aspnetcore</PackageTags>
    <SignAssembly>false</SignAssembly>
    <ProjectGuid>{9BCDBAA0-141F-404B-864B-74A35A476AAD}</ProjectGuid>
    <RepositoryUrl></RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>Private</RepositoryType>
    <Authors></Authors>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NEST" Version="6.3.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Any ideas why?  I added extra permissions to the folder for Reading/Writing that the agent uses, no joy.  I also changed from Network Service to a higher privileged account and still get the issue.  Restarted machine multiple times.

This was working up until yesterday.  Has anyone else faced this particular issue?

Thanks for any pointers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround , you can delete the `_work` folder and rebuild to generate a new `_work` folder.